# Formatting text in tabular form with Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, format

```
propertiesTextBlock = """
    Basic Properties
    ----------------
    - nodes (n)         {n}
    - edges (m)         {m}
    - min. degree           {minDeg}
    - max. degree           {maxDeg}
    - isolated nodes        {isolates}
    - self-loops            {loops}
    - density           {dens:10.6f}
"""
```

Several data items are inserted using `string.format`. Output to console then looks like:

```
Basic Properties
----------------
- nodes (n)         10680
- edges (m)         24316
- min. degree           1
- max. degree           205
- isolated nodes        0
- self-loops            0
- density             0.000426
```

Not perfect, because I need to manually insert exactly the right amount of tabs in the text block. Also, what if I want to align the numbers differently (e.g right-justify everything, align at `.` ...)
Is there an easy way to make sure that this table looks nice?

Comment: Are you ok to use [prettytable](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/) format instead of this tabular form?

Comment: @alecxe Ideally, I want the output to be in markdown format. Is prettytable compatible with that?

Comment: You do know that the format syntax supports aligning text left or right?

Comment: @cls nope, prettytable is just for visualizing tables

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, did not know that. How exactly?

Comment: @cls also take a look at [tabulate](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate) module, might help.

Comment: @cls: I made that into an answer below; it was getting a little too verbose for a comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [format mini language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) to specify alignments:

```
>>> print '- nodes (n) {n:>20}\n- edges (m) {m:>20}'.format(n=1234, m=234)
- nodes (n)                 1234
- edges (m)                  234
```

The `>20` formatting specification sets the field width to 20 characters and right-aligns the value in that field.

This does *not* support alignment by decimal point, however. You *can* specify dynamic field widths though:

```
>>> print '- nodes (n) {n:>{width}}'.format(n=123, width=5)
- nodes (n)   123
>>> print '- nodes (n) {n:>{width}}'.format(n=123, width=10)
- nodes (n)        123
```

which you can adapt to add or remove whitespace around a floating point number:

```
>>> from math import log10
>>> print '- density {density:>{width}.6f}'.format(density=density, width=10-int(log10(int(density))))
- density  0.000426
>>> density = 10.000426
>>> print '- density {density:>{width}.6f}'.format(density=density, width=10-int(log10(int(density))))
- density 10.000426
```

Here the field width is adjusted to shift the decimal point left or right based on how much space the whole value is going to take. Note that the field width is the *total* width, so including the decimal point and the 6 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

The *right* answer is maybe to use [`prettytable`](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/) or [`tabulate`](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate).

If you want to stay with plain old format, you could control field width:

```
>>> print "node:{0:16}".format(10680,);
node:           10680
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
#      16 characters
```

For *float* values you could align to the decimal point:

```
>>> print "node:{0:16.2f}".format(10680.); \
... print "node:{0:16.2f}".format(10.5)
... print "node:{0:16.2f}".format(123.456)
node:        10680.00
node:           10.50
node:          123.46
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
#      16 characters
```

Here is the formal description of the "format mini-language": http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings